# React navigation : FragmentManager is already executing transanctions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was using [BottomTabNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation) to create tabs navigation in react native with nested Stack navigation, but when I want to implement the same logic with [createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/), I get this error. here's the code :

```
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
    const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

    
    const HomeStack = () => {
        return <Stack.Navigator>
                   <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={options} />
                   <Stack.Screen name="TodoDetail" component={TodoDetail} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    }
    
    export default function App() {
        return (
           <NavigationContainer>
              <TopTab.Navigator>
                 <TopTab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeStack} />
                 <TopTab.Screen name='About' component={About} />
              </TopTab.Navigator>
           </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
```

here is the error in the device :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the definition of `TopTab`, but the current implementation leads to the issue.

The `TopTab` navigation must be in a `Stack.Screen`. forget about the `BottomTabNavigation`, it uses a different approach to show the screens.

So You must use `TopTabNavigation` inside of a `screen`

Just for an example with the current implementation:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

const topBarStack = () => {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator>
      <TopTab.Screen name='first-tab' component={firstTab} />
      <TopTab.Screen name='second-tab' component={secondTab} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  )
}
    
export default function App() {
  return (     
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={topBarStack} options={options} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TodoDetail" component={TodoDetail} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```